freertos stack does not overflow
Hello good people of internet
I was studying FreeRTOS, I expect myTaskA to overflow the stack but it does not. How come?
FreeRTOSConfig.h
#define configCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW           2

// demo 2 : allocating huge array in stack to ovf
static void app_myTaskA( void * pvParameters ) {
    uint32_t myHugeArray[APP_DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE+1];
    printf("remStack: %d\n", (int)uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark(NULL));
    uint32_t anotherU32 = 0;
    printf("remStack: %d\n", (int)uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark(NULL));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(myHugeArray); ++i) {
        // implementing sth so compiler does not optimize out
        myHugeArray[i] = i;
        myHugeArray[i]++;
        myHugeArray[i]--;
        anotherU32++;
    }

    while(1) { // to see if task survives and prints remaining stack constantly
        int remStack = (int)uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark(NULL);
        if (remStack) {
            printf("remStack: %d\n", remStack);
        } else {
            printf("no remStack\n");
        }
    }
}


Terminal Output
QEMU_started
remStack: 1014
remStack: 1014
no remStack
no remStack
no remStack


It will only crash if you write over something important. The OS can only check the stack once you call a OS function or return from the task.

I actually missed that you call (int)uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark(NULL). But maybe there is still no checking. Maybe try to return from the task and see if the hook is then executed. Also the output seems to be correct, what would you expect differently?

I agree, I expected the output. I was expecting vApplicationStackOverflowHook this hook to be triggered tho. For example if I do recursive call of app_myTaskA in the while, hook gets triggered.

I had a look into the code of the function and it seems it does not make a callback to OS internals. When you invoke a task, then the stack checks are triggered for sure.

I understand. I created another task called B. now output is:
'no remStack'
'no'
'Stack overflow in A'
I guess this is due context switching between tasks?

Did the OS switch from A to B and there was still no Hook called?

Hook is called. Hook prints 'Stack overflow in A'. Hmm actually let me look tracing output. Thx btw

Glad to help! :)

I'll add this as a answer if you don't mind.

haha my laptop battery died. ofc it is okay. I could not give upvote tho since this account is new

The function call (int)uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark(NULL) (GitHub link) does not make a callback into OS internals. No checking is therefore performed and the task never returns from the loop.
If you return from the task or call another OS function, that will mack a callback to OS (possibly resource handling calls), then the OS will call the OS checking logic.
Same also when the task will get preempted by another task.
